# Criar um sistema de Atualização - Java

Tags: java, atualização

Boa tarde galera,

Desenvolvi um sistema onde dependo de ficar fazer atualizações e manutenções no sistema. Mas estou tendo dificuldades em distribuir as atualizações pois ele é sistema Desktop.
Existe um sistema que faça isso, ou devo criar um sistema que faça isso?

como eu faria isso?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Olá Felipe, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Marquei sua pergunta como duplicata porque ela já existe. Infelizmente, a outra resposta também foi suspensa porque não está claro. Do jeito que está, sua pergunta tem muitas possibilidades de resposta, já que não tem requisitos claros do que exatamente você precisa. Por exemplo, isso vai envolver atualização do banco de dados? Seria somente sobrescrever os arquivos atuais? Isso vai ser automático ou depende do usuário clicar em algo? Seu sistema tem instalador ou é apenas um jar?

Comment: Enfim, uma resposta simplista seria simplesmente fazer um programa que faça o download da versão mais nova e coloque os arquivos no lugar do sistema atual. Provavelmente existem muitas soluções de mercado para automatizar isso, mas dependendo de como cada aplicação funciona pode ter alguns desafios no processo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certa vez precisei fazer um "atualizador de versão" para um aplicação VB. O resumo da obra seria, o usuário clica no atualizador(ele sequer sabe que há outro executavel além desse) que, por sua vez, busca no repositório FTP por uma versão mais nova, havendo ele baixa, descompacta, copia os arquivos para as pastas corretas, roda scripts sql no banco, atualiza registros do sistema operacional e no fim executa a aplicação.
Vantagens deste formato - não há custo
Desvantagens deste formato - muito código escrito para uma tarefa simples

Outro meio, bem mais interessante, é utilizar um servidor de integração continua, tipo [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), desta forma vocẽ continuaria precisando de um "atualizador" mas poderia empacotar separadamente suas bibliotecas e diminuir a quantidade de código, logo a manutenção, no seu atualizador.

Uma terceira, pensei nela agora mas acho ainda mais legal, seria distribuir o [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) com sua aplicação, utilizar plugins existentes ou criar os seus com a finalidade de recuperar releases (SCM, ftp ou servidor de integração continua), atualizar banco de dados (scripts ou hibernate).

Enfim, visto que você não vai conseguir sobrescrever um arquivo em execução o caminho mais simples é ter um atualizador (hoje é muito comum, os tais lauchers) e que seu cliente só "conheça" ele, sendo dele a responsábilidade de atualizar e/ou executar o que hoje é seu arquivo "main".

Não conheço solução pronta pra este caso, espero ter dado uma luz na sua busca.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!
Valeu, mesmo!